# Setting folders ACL for local groups

Tags: permissions, powershell, acl, windows-server-2016

i need to grant permissions of a couple of local folders for a specific local group. I'm using `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule`. And it looks like this:

```
$aclFolders =  Join-Path -Path $env:windir -ChildPath "\temp\"
$group = "sql\IIS_IUSRS"
$Acl = Get-Acl $aclFolders
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($group, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $aclFolders $Acl
```

`sql\IIS_IUSRS` is a local group  If I run the script on it (or even with sql\Administrators) i get this:

> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all
>   identity references could not be translated." At
>   C:\projects\dsc.quickstart\sitecore-web-role\install.ps1:16 char:1
>   + $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

I'm wondering if that function would only work with users and not also with groups. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Eventually it came up that the correct domain for local built-in groups is: `BUILTIN\a-group` and when running the script on `BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS` it just works.

Answer (score 2):

On W10 systems rolled out in their own language it fails as well. "Everyone" is not translated to "Iedereen" So for standard SID's better Use the GUI

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path <FolderName> 

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-1-0")
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$Name = $objUser.Value


Write-Host $Name #will show translated sid in local language
        $InheritanceFlag = @([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit,[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)
        $PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("$Name","FullControl",$InheritanceFlag,$PropagationFlag,"Allow")
        $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
        Set-Acl -Path <FolderName> -AclObject $acl -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```